# Solving the source free Maxwell equations for plane waves

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I've been trying to solve the maxwell equations:
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{D}=0,\quad \nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t},\quad \nabla\times\vec{H}=\frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}$$
Where $\vec{D}=\epsilon \vec{E}$, $\vec{B}=\mu_0 \vec{H}$
Here $\epsilon$ is the three by three matrix:
$$\epsilon=\epsilon_0A$$
Where $A$ is symmetric and $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$ are the usual constants. I've been looking for plane wave solutions, real part implied, of the form
$$\vec{D}=\vec{D_0}e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t)},\quad \vec{B}=\vec{B_0}e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t)}$$
By solve here I mean find conditions on $\vec{D_0},\vec{B_0},\vec{k}$ only in terms of $\omega$. By substitution I have found these relations:
$$\vec{k}\cdot\vec{D_0}=0,\quad\vec{k}\cdot\vec{B_0}=0$$
$$\vec{k}\times\frac1\epsilon_0A^{-1}\vec{D_0}=\omega\vec{B_0},\quad-\vec{k}\times\vec{B_0}=\mu_0\omega\vec{D_0}$$
I want to figure this out on my own, but I've been playing with these things for a long time now and I believe to get this in the form $\vec{D_0}=\vec{D_0}(\omega),\vec{B_0}=\vec{B_0}(\omega),\vec{k}=\vec{k}(\omega)$, requires some knowledge outside of my skill set, I would much appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Try picking orthogonal directions (i.e., $\hat{k}\perp\vec{B}\perp\vec{D}$)

Comment: @KyleKanos: Ok, so $\vec{k}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{B}$, however by the 4th equation $\vec{D}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{B}$. So they must all be perpendicular to each other?
But the 3rd equation states that $\vec{B}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{k}$ and a transformed $\vec{D}$, does this imply my calculations were wrong?

Comment: Yes, take each to be perpendicular to each other. Recall that $\hat{z}\times\hat{x}=\hat{y}$.

Comment: @KyleKanos: So they are wrong, ok. However I feel that I would get a similar set of equations anyway, what would the general approach be there to achieve my desired result?

Comment: How are they wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought when you said 'yes' you were referring to my question I asked in my first comment. Equations $1,2$ and $4$ imply they are all mutually perpendicular, however $3$ implies $\vec{B}$ is perpendicular to a $A^{-1}\vec{D}$.

Ah, so does that imply that $A^{-1}$ rotates $\vec{D}$ round in the $\vec{D},\vec{k}$ plane?

Comment: Set $\hat{k}=\hat{z}$ and then pick the other two directions ($y$ & $x$) for the two fields and see what you get when you take the cross products.